# Why can a function change the object on the outside?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, object, namespaces

see the example below:

```
def func(arg):
    print(id(arg))
    df = pd.DataFrame(arg)
    print(id(df))
    df['b'] = [4,5,6]

a = pd.DataFrame( {'a' : [1,2,3]})

print(a, id(a))

func(a)

print(a)
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3 
681924702104
681924702104
681924718944
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Why does a Change after calling the function ? I don't get it especially because they have all different id's. What would be the correct proceeding to fix this?

Comment: Does `df = pd.DataFrame(arg); df['b'] = [4,5,6]` modify `arg`? I'm not familiar with that class.

Comment: not sure, but 1: you created a new `DataFrame` object, but it seems to modify the original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame()` takes an argument that specifies whether it should copy the data. The default is `False`. If you want a copy, set it to `True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arg, copy=True)
```

This'll fix your example.

Comment: or `df = a.copy()`.

Comment: But since a and df have different identity (thus they are different objects according to[link]( https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id )) how is it possible to change a by adding column 'b' to df ?